# How to count matches in two arrays?

Tags: arrays, julia

If I have two arrays, how can I count the number of matching elements?

E.g. with

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [3,4,5,6]
```

I'd like to get the count (`3`) of the three matching elements `3`,`4`,and `5`.

Comment: how do you want to handle duplicates?

Comment: Maybe both cases would be good to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`intersect`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.intersect):

```
julia> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5

julia> y = [3, 4, 5, 6]
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 3
 4
 5
 6

julia> intersect(Set(x), Set(y))
Set{Int64} with 3 elements:
  5
  4
  3

julia> length(intersect(Set(x), Set(y)))
3
```

Answer (score 3):

A lot depends on the sizes of the arrays. If the arrays are just a few dozen integers in length, a simple O(N^2) count wins over the count_matches sorting method and the intersect count_matches0 methods above, because of zero allocation setup time:

```
function count_matches2(x, y)
    count(n -> any(==(n), x), y)
end

@btime count_matches(x, y)  setup=(x = rand(1:100,50); y = rand(1:100,50)) evals=1
@btime count_matches0(x, y) setup=(x = rand(1:100,50); y = rand(1:100,50)) evals=1
@btime count_matches2(x, y)  setup=(x = rand(1:100,50); y = rand(1:100,50)) evals=1

2.400 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
3.700 μs (10 allocations: 3.59 KiB)
1.500 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

The simplicity advantage vanishes with arrays of size > 1000.

Answer (score 2):

The following algorithm can be near 4X faster than Set intersection. The idea is to sort the arrays first, that has `O(n log n)` complexity for each array. Then merge-compare the sorted versions for equal elements, that has `O(m + n)` linear complexity. So, the overall algorithm complexity can be `O(n log n)`.

This algorithm counts duplicate elements into the final matches result, but can be modified with a small overhead to behave similarly to sets. The modification can include adding a variable to keep track of the last matched elements and increment the number of matches only for new different matched pairs.

```
function count_matches(x,y)
    sort!(x) # or x = sort(x) 
    sort!(y) # or y = sort(y)
    i = j = 1
    matches = 0
    while i <= length(x) && j <= length(y)
        if x[i] == y[j]
            i += 1 
            j += 1
            matches += 1
        elseif x[i] < y[j]
            i += 1
        else 
            j += 1
        end
    end 
    matches
end
```

Comparing with:

```
function count_matches0(x,y)
    length(intersect(Set(x), Set(y)))
end
```

and timing with `n = 10000` arrays, we get:

```
@btime count_matches(x, y)  setup=(x = rand(1:1000,10000); y = rand(1:1000,10000)) evals=1
@btime count_matches0(x, y) setup=(x = rand(1:1000,10000); y = rand(1:1000,10000)) evals=1
  246.700 μs (31 allocations: 338.31 KiB)
  63.200 μs (2 allocations: 15.88 KiB)
```